# How to decode the following json?

Tags: php, json, twitter

[image]

Hi i am unable to take out the text field in the JSON shown above.

```
       $json = json_encode($response);
  echo $json;

 $decode = json_decode($json, true);
$decode = reset($decode);




   $count = count($decode);
    echo $count;

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){


       $latestTweet = htmlentities($json[$i]->text, ENT_QUOTES);
$latestTweet = preg_replace('/http:\/\/([a-z0-9_\.\-\+\&\!\#\~\/\,]+)/i', '<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">http://$1</a>', $latestTweet);
$latestTweet = preg_replace('/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $latestTweet);
echo $latestTweet;



    }
```

I get this error: 
`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\Vini\Documents\My Web Sites\twitteroauth-master\test.php on line 79`

Comment: Check & Post `var_dump(json_decode($json,true));`.

Comment: where is $json defined? appearantly json is not an object as you expect it to be.

Comment: The response is the array and i am converting it into json please check my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode) function takes an associative array and returns a json string.  you are trying to use a string as an object (with ->). that is why you are getting this error. 
[json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) however takes a json string and returns object by default.

Comment: so how do i get the text field from the json string in php?

Comment: use json_decode without a second parameter (not like you did with $decode) and you'll get an object.